# calling Post from different script AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to use a post to access a server side boolean method.
It works fine in the controller like this.

```
$http.post(ROOT + '/step/ReadOnly/' + $scope.problemId)
        .success(function (result) {
            $scope.problemCompleted = result;

        })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("problemCompleted not sent")
        return false;
    });
```

The problem is that I will be using this method in a lot of different controllers. So what I wanted to do is put the post into a service and just call it from there like this.

**Service**

```
//readOnly
this.readOnly = function (Id) {
    $http.post(ROOT + '/step/ReadOnly/' + Id)
        .success(function (result) {
            var problemCompleted = result;
            return problemCompleted;
        })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("problemCompleted not sent")
        return false;
    });
};
```

and then call it in any controller like this.

```
$scope.problemCompleted = stepService.readOnly($scope.problemId);
```

It still calls the server side controller but the page seems to finish loading before it gets the response. The server side controller gets the right `problemId` . It just seems the page loads up before it gets the result from the post and my `$scope.problemCompleted` is undefined.
It doesn't hit the `.success` or `.error` it just seems to skip over it so I don't get any `result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't [return from asynchronous code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). What you can and should do in your case is return [Promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) object and in controller chain to its then-able API:

```
this.readOnly = function (Id) {
    return $http.post(ROOT + '/step/ReadOnly/' + Id).success(function (result) {
        return problemCompleted;
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("problemCompleted not sent");
        return false;
    });
};
```

In controller:

```
stepService.readOnly($scope.problemId).then(function(data) {
    $scope.problemCompleted = data;    
});
```

Comment: @EricColgan You should not create redundant deferred object, as `$http` already returns Promise object.

Comment: Ah perfect I understand it now. I'm using it your way now it's a lot cleaner. Cheers